# MsAccessで、OneDrive上に保存してあるaccdbファイルにリンクして操作する方法

Tags: ms-access

お世話になります。

MicrosoftAccess2019を使用して、社内で使用するシステムを作成しているのですが、
データ本体をOneDriveに配置できないかと試行錯誤しているのですが、なかなかうまくいかずに
困っています。

OneDriveにサインインし、ネットワークドライブを割り当て、そのファイルにアクセスして
リンクを張ろうとしたのですが、下記のようなエラーが出てしまい、先に進めませんでした。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

社内だけであれば、既存の共有ドライブにファイルを置いておけば良いのですが、
外から使用するためにクラウドからアクセスできればと思い、試してみました。

解決方法を教えていただきたいのですが、もしかするとVPNを使用してファイルアクセスを
したほうのが良いのかとも考えています。

OneDriveからアクセスする方法をお教えいただけますでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 出来るように見えるけれどトラブルの基らしいですね。古い版の情報ですが[Access 2013 をOneDriveに置いた場合に、どのような問題が発生しますか?](https://answers.microsoft.com/ja-jp/msoffice/forum/all/access-2013/a6137f79-f7f4-46c6-b537-c7517b246040), [access2010　onedrive上でのテーブルのリンク](https://answers.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/forum/office_2010-access/access2010/1f31831d-5eca-46ac-ae43-addc7b1e9b66), [Using MS Access on OneDrive](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/using-ms-access-on-onedrive/880e752f-9d66-41d9-838e-d80e45ba5a17), [Access デスクトップ データベースを共有する方法](https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/03822632-da43-4d8f-ba2a-68da245a0446)

Comment: いつも早速のご返答、ありがとうございます。とても助かっています。なんかできないということらしいですね。だとすると、VPNにするか、もしくはSharePointにするかという方法がありそうですが、教えていただいた先のMSのサイトの画像に、『ワークロード』というのがあって、『明るい』、『濃い』とありますが、これはどういうことなのでしょうね。『濃い』とは遅いということなのですかね。

Comment: SharePointも方法によっては問題ありそうなので、注意が必要でしょうね。それからワークロード=仕事量でしょうから、明るいはLight(軽い)で濃いはHeavy(重い)/Deep(深い)/Severe(厳しい)あたりでは？